# Literature recommendation: Stability analysis for a constrained class of systems (or functions)

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I am working on a special class of problem (in a grey area between mathematics and engineering :D), of course in system theory where the systems' states doesn't take values in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ (Since I am narrowing a bit down, I am only considering the real values as of now) but instead takes the values in the set $\mathbb{Z}$. Formally, let the function  be defined as follows:

$\dot x=f(x)$

where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So having said this the question is that, of course after quite some deep literature surveys, whether is there any books (or literature of any kind) that explicitly addresses the construction of Lyapunov functions or methods to prove the stability for the above-mentioned class of functions/systems.

All your constructive comments are answers are welcomed.

Comment: My comments didn't carry over (and I didn't expect them to) but they were also removed from the original post (which I also didn't expect), but, anyway, saying the states don't take values in $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ ($\{\infty\}$, not $\infty$) isn't accurate because $\Bbb Z \subseteq \Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$.  For your actual question, it sounds like you want info about lyapunov functions/methods for stability of discrete systems?  [Page 13 here](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~apnoco/Lectures2015/03_Lyapunov.pdf) may be a good start.

Comment: @tilper Even I didn't expect that. Anyway, the system/function can be anything either discrete/ continuous, the internal states $x$ only takes integer values and not real values. That is they serve as an integer-valued 
 state map rather than a real/complex-valued state map. I have come across a lot of literature that discusses the latter, but I never came across a single literature that deals with the former case. And I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

Lyapunov stability is ultimately tied to the topology of the space in question, because it has to do with convergence, which is, most generally, a topological notion. The natural topology for the integers, which it inherits as a subset of the reals, is the discrete topology, where convergence is no different than: takes the value in question after finitely many steps (and continues to take that value from then on). As a consequence, I doubt the analogous notion to Lyapunov stability will give any interesting or useful results.

Comment: Actually, it does, as a baseline in a weaker notion, when viewed as impact maps (a type of Poincare map). So this is the reason for me to search the literature for such a class. Moreover, you are right in your observation and reasoning.